# Remove view action extension at runtime

Tags: eclipse, view, registry, rcp

I do have created a View and these View is used in multiple products, we already have delivered.
The View is placed in a feature and these feature does not know the product specification and the feature should not know.

Other plugins contribute actions to the view, which are shown in the view toolbar title, by implementing the extension point

- "org.eclipse.ui.viewActions"

Depending on a system property (the product specification will set at runtime) all contributed view actions should be hidden or not.

Question:
i was not able to find a class, for removing deleting extension for a special extension point. I know that the

- WorkbenchPlugin.getDefault().getActionSetRegistry()

can remove actionSets, but does something similuar exists for the viewActions?

I looked into the code and found a solution, but this is totally not acceptable, because it could/will break, when i update my eclipse target platform, because of the reflection call.

```
Field privateStringField = ExtensionRegistry.class.getDeclaredField("masterToken"); //$NON-NLS-1$
privateStringField.setAccessible(true);
Object masterToken = privateStringField.get(registry);

// Reads the External Datatype Providers
IExtensionPoint extensionPoint = registry.getExtensionPoint("org.eclipse.ui.viewActions"); //$NON-NLS-1$
IConfigurationElement[] extensionPointArray = extensionPoint.getConfigurationElements();

for (int i = 0; i < extensionPointArray.length; i++) {
    IConfigurationElement element = extensionPointArray[i];
    if (element.getAttribute("targetID").equalsIgnoreCase(pPartId)) { //$NON-NLS-1$
        IConfigurationElement[] childs = element.getChildren();
        for (int j = 0; j < childs.length; j++) {
            registry.removeExtension(element.getDeclaringExtension(), masterToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll just add that in an RCP app, you can use a preference `IRegistryConstants.PROP_REGISTRY_NULL_USER_TOKEN` to set the user token to null, and then you don't need reflection.  See http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/144647/455309/#msg_455309

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Product Customization](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Product_Customization) to modify the extensions XML as it is loaded.  Then products that need to can can use the Product Customization and a style sheet.  ex, to suppress an action:

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:template match="actionSet[@id='org.eclipse.ui.edit.text.actionSet.convertLineDelimitersTo']">
   </xsl:template>
   <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
       <xsl:copy>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
       </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

You could also try [Activities/Capabilities](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_scalability.htm) to hide the viewActions.  Each product that needs to would include disabled activities to make the viewActions extensions disappear.